# How to reduce memory use, searching for the kth character in a sequence?

Tags: string, algorithm, memory, out-of-memory

**Problem Statement:**

A teacher once said: "Good writing is good writing is good writing."
Hence, the teacher defines f0= "Good writing is good writing is good writing."
To make the quote more interesting the teacher defines fn= "Good writing is good " +fn−1+ " writing is good " +fn−1+ " is good writing." for all n≥1

For example, f1 is:

`Good writing is good Good writing is good writing is good writing. writing is good Good writing is good writing is good writing. is good writing.`

Note that the quotation marks are not part of f1.

The teacher wants to ask q questions. Each time she wants to find the k-th character of fn.
Characters are indexed starting at 1. If fn consists of less than k characters, output `.`

In all tests,

1≤q≤10

0≤n≤30

1≤k≤2<sup>31−1</sup>

For example:

input:

```
3
0 4
1 100
1 1111111
```

output:

```
d
g
.
```

input:

```
3
0 6  
1 13
1 22
```

output:

```
w

G
```

**My problem:**

What I've done so far is simply create an array that stores the precomputed strings of f0 to f31.

```
        String[] f = new String[31];
        f[0] = "Good writing is good writing is good writing.";
        f[1] = "Good writing is good Good writing is good writing is good writing. writing is good Good writing is good writing is good writing. is good writing.";
        for(int i = 2; i < 31; i++) {
            f[i] = "Good writing is good " + f[i-1] + " writing is good " + f[i-1] + " is good writing.";
        }
```

Once I've precomputed the max of 31, I query the input:

```
        while(q-->0) {
            int n = readInt();
            int k = readInt();
            System.out.println(f[n]);
            if(f[n].length() < k) {
                System.out.println(".");
            } else {
                System.out.println(f[n].charAt(k-1));
            }
        }
```

Now the problem with this is that when do this, I get a *Out of Memory Error*. This led me to think that there is a much faster and easier way of doing this question. I *feel* like there is a pattern, but I might be wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that each string is more than twice as long as the previous one.  f30 is several dozen gigabytes in length.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you, but once again, do you think there's a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest doing this instead: Build a table of the length of f*i*, the point in the string where the previous string (f*i-1*) appears the first time, and the point where it appears the second time.

Comment: @BenVoigt by f*i* do you mean f*n*?

Comment: I mean `f[i]` like inside your preparation for loop, not `f[n]` where `n = readInt()`

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm still a bit confused about your solution, could you kindly code a bit of it up please? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199474/discussion-between-timothyw553-and-ben-voigt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to determine where in the added sections the kth character is. For that we can make the previous call return the length of its result rather than the result itself in addition to the kth character. Then we can decide where in the sections the kth falls. The following code also returns the string but just for purposes of demonstration.

You can see that in our function, `f(n, k)`, if we determine the kth character falls inside one of the the sections that are `f(n - 1)`, we subtract from `k` the length of the preceding section/s and obtain `kth` from `f(n - 1, k - length_of_prefix)` since it's just like looking for the (new) kth inside `f(n - 1)`. We perform that search recursively as needed.

JavaScript code:

```js
// Returns [len_fn, kth, fn]
function f(n, k){
  const f_0 = "Good writing is good writing is good writing."
  const len_0 = f_0.length
  
  const str_1 = "Good writing is good "
  const str_2 = " writing is good "
  const str_3 = " is good writing."
  const len_1 = str_1.length
  const len_2 = str_2.length
  const len_3 = str_3.length
  
  if (n == 0)
    return [len_0, f_0[k-1], f_0]
  
  const [len_fn1, kth1, fn1] = f(n - 1)
  const fn = str_1 + fn1 + str_2 + fn1 + str_3
  
  const len_fn = len_1 + len_fn1 + len_2 + len_fn1 + len_3
  const pos_fn1_2 = len_1 + len_fn1 + len_2
  
  if (k <= len_1)
    return [len_fn, str_1[k-1], fn]
    
  // kth is in f(n - 1)
  else if (k <= len_1 + len_fn1){
    const kth = f(n - 1, k - len_1)[1]
    return [len_fn, kth, fn]
  }
  
  else if (k <= pos_fn1_2)
    return [len_fn, str_2[k-len_1-len_fn1-1], fn]
    
  // kth is in f(n - 1)
  else if (k <= pos_fn1_2 + len_fn1){
    const kth = f(n - 1, k - pos_fn1_2)[1]
    return [len_fn, kth, fn]
  }
    
  else
    return [len_fn, str_3[k-pos_fn1_2-len_fn1-1], fn]
}
   
var result = f(2, 253)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
console.log("")
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  result[2].split("").map((x, i) => [i + 1, x])))
```

Comment: could you explain these sections of code please, I'm not really familiar with JavaScript

Comment: ```const [len_fn1, kth1, fn1] = f(n - 1)```
and

Comment: ```console.log(JSON.stringify( fn.split("").map((x, i) => [i + 1, x])))```

Comment: @TimothyW553 sure. `const [len_fn1, kth1, fn1] = f(n - 1)`: since the function `f` returns an array of three items, that assigns them at once to the three variables, `len_fn1, kth1, fn1`. The second one you asked about, `console.log(JSON.stringify( fn.split("").map((x, i) => [i + 1, x])))` logs `fn`, which is the long string result, as a list of tuples so we can see the index of each character and more easily confirm that the answer returned by the function is correct.

Comment: @TimothyW553 I amended the code slightly to manually log the indexed string after the result, rather than as part of the recursion.